# There seem to be at least 2 ways to do backtracking, How does this specific approach of backtracking really work?

Tags: c++, algorithm, design-patterns, computer-science, backtracking

So i'm working on solving a combinational problem (find the powerset) using recursive backtracking and noticed that there is a template to do backtracking problems.

**problem statement: *Given a set of distinct integers, nums, return all possible subsets (the power set).***

For a given set of N distinct integers there are 2^N combinations. So one can compute it using the following algorithm where 'cur' stores the partial combination, and 'allSubsets' is called itself 2 times within its body: 1 without the i'th element added to 'cur', and the 2nd call after the i'th element added to 'cur' (after cur.emplace_back and before cur.pop_back)

**approach-1:**

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> subsets(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector < vector<int>> res;
        vector <int> cur;
        allSubsets(nums, cur, 0, res);
        return res;
    }  
    void allSubsets(vector<int>& v, vector<int>& cur, int idx, vector<vector<int>>& res) {
        if (idx == v.size()) {
            res.emplace_back(cur);
            return;
        } 
        allSubsets(v, cur, idx+1, res);
        cur.emplace_back(v[idx]);
        allSubsets(v, cur, idx+1, res);
        cur.pop_back();
    }
};
```

This approach above of recursive backtracking is understandable due to the reasoning that for every element we are considering two paths-- 1 with elements included and the 2nd with element excluded.

But I recently saw this following backtracking approach to do the same (generate all subsets), which doesn't make sense to me. It doesn't seem similar to above as genSets is being called a variable # of times within its body than exact 2 times in the previous approach.

**approach-2:**

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> subsets(vector<int>& nums) {
        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
        vector<vector<int>> subs;
        vector<int> sub;  
        genSubsets(nums, 0, sub, subs);
        return subs; 
    }
    void genSubsets(vector<int>& nums, int start, vector<int>& sub, vector<vector<int>>& subs) {
        subs.push_back(sub);
        for (int i = start; i < nums.size(); i++) {
            sub.push_back(nums[i]);
            genSubsets(nums, i + 1, sub, subs);
            sub.pop_back();
        }
    }
};
```

**So how is it doing the same work?  In 'genSubsets' where are subsets that exclude the current index being formed?**

**If nums was {1, 2, 3, 4}, where would the subset {1, 2, 3} get constructed as we don't call genSubsets are pop_back or before sub.push_back?**

*I've spent hours trying to understand this second approach with no luck and confused how it works and is similar to the approach-1 above?*

Comment: Counting up in an integer variable generates all possible subsets as the binary values of that variable. That's way simpler than the recursive approaches. Also extremely much more efficient.

Comment: @Alf but the question is specifically about approach-2 as that template can be used for many more backtracking problems besides subsets

Answer (score 1):

The binomial theorem says that you can write `2^N = C(N,0) + C(N,1) + ... + C(N,N-1) + C(N,N)` where `C(n,k)` is the number of ways to choose k elements from a set of n. This is the way version 2 is counting the power set.

The first subset constructed is the empty set (0 elements). Then inside the for loop, each branch (depth first) constructs a subset with 1 element. Inside each one of those for loops, a subset is created with 2 elements. Etc.

Comment: i mean this binomial equation is fine, but how does it connect to approach-2 in that it isn't obvious if the K'th iteration of the loop computes C(n, k) and how? in approach-1 the call-tree is branched 2 times in every recursive call so it's easy to see 2^N, but in this case each recursive call leads to N more calls, so N^N and which iteration of loop computes which term in the binomial equation?

Comment: The for loop runs from `start` to N, not 0 to N. The value `start` is modified at each step. So no, it's not N^N. There are N+1 levels of recursion and each level k from O to N computes C(N,k) subsets. In the {1,2,3,4} example, the 0th level computes the empty set. The 1st for loop computes the sets: {1} ,{2}, {3}, {4} - all sets with 1 element. After the set {1} is constructed, all subsets with 2 elements {1, X} for X=2,3,4 are computed. After the set {2} is constructed, all subsets with 2 elements {2, X} for X=3,4 are constructed. So, the 2nd recursive level constructs all 2 element subsets.